# mysql compares accented vs unaccented characters as the same?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

This does not make sense to me. Can anyone explain it? I think the column values should be different, so

```
select * from a1 where f1 = f2;
```

should find no rows. But...

```
mysql> create table a1 (f1 varchar(63), f2 varchar(63));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table a1 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: a1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `a1` (
  `f1` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f2` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> insert into a1 values ('EFBBBFD187D0B5D0BBD0BED0B2D0B5D0BA', 'EFBBBFD187D0B5D0BBD0BED0B2D0B5CC81D0BA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> update a1 set f1 = unhex(f1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update a1 set f2 = unhex(f2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from a1;
+-------------------+---------------------+
| f1                | f2                  |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| ﻿человек          | ﻿челове́к           |
+-------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> select * from a1 where f1 = f2;
+-------------------+---------------------+
| f1                | f2                  |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| ﻿человек          | ﻿челове́к           |
+-------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from a1 where hex(f1) = hex(f2);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I use `select BINARY()....`, instead of HEX(), that is what is recommended for this problem elsewhere for handling uppercase vs lowercase selections.  Logically they should be the same, I know, just mentioning what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 bytes on the beginning, `EFBBBF`, is "BOM", which indicates that the text is UTF-8-encoded.

The rest look like Cyrillic `челове́к`, except for the "CC81 --  NSM  COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT"

Some collations, including `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, handle "combining accents", some do not.  The "ai" means "accent insensitive".

I would understand this equivalence for a "latin" `e`.  I don't know the rules for a CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE, which looks the same `е`, but is encoded differently.

You might want `COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`, which is "accent sensitive and case insensitive".

Comment: [10.3.1 Collation Naming Conventions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html) is the source for this explanation. It also links [UCA 9.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/9.0.0/allkeys.txt) where you can see which variants of "_small latin letter e_" is considered same (`.1CAA.0020.0002`): homoglyphs like "_cyrillic small letter ie_" have their own group (`.205A.0020.0002`).

Answer (score 0):

Character equivalence is defined by the collation used by the columns in question. A collation defines every pair of characters as equal, less than, or greater than, and this is used for comparisons and for sorting.

Your table uses `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` as the default collation, and this applies to all the columns, since they do not define a collation to override the table's default.

It's pretty common for collations to treat accented characters as equal to their unaccented versions.

If you want to choose a different collation, you may.